# Netlogo - member of one breed ask variable value of member of another breed

Tags: netlogo

I have a member of `breed A` asking neighbouring agents, members of `breed B` and `breed C`, which value they have for `var` each tick.

When I run a code for members of `breed A` I get the following error:
`PEOPLES breed does not own variable VAR
error while people 1005 running VAR`

The code only for members of `breed A`is:

`rt random 360
 fd 5
  ask peoples-on neighbors [
    if var > 5 [ ;; var of members of breed B and C
    die
    ]
  ]`

I understand that `breed A` does not own var, but I want `breed A` ask the values of `var` of `breed B` and `breed C`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the of operator which will return a list of variables of all the breeds B and C

```
let varsForBs [var] of B-here
let varsForCs [var] of C-here
```

If you have only one B and C, you can just take the first element from the list.